# PHP: Convert a string containing a mathematical formula into a multi dimensional array so is it can be calculated programatically without using eval()

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match, strpos, preg-split

I’m trying to convert a formula like;

```
(1 + 21) * ((2 * 10) + 90)
```

Into a multi dimensional array structured as such

```
* func
    * the function that joins this array to the next
* val
    * the value
* calc
    * contains an array of further (func, val, calc)
```

So as it can be processed via a function similar to;

```
public function processCalculation($calcs, $data){
              $value = false;
                    ///Loop through the Calculation arrays
                    foreach($calcs as $i => $calc){
                         if(isset($calc['calc'])) $val = $this->processCalculation($calc['calc'], $data);
                         elseif(isset($calc['val'])) $val = $calc['val'];

                         if($value === false && !isset($calc['func'])) $value = $val;
                         else $value = $this->doCalculation($calc['func'], $value, $val);
                    }

                   return $value;
     }
```

(doCalculation simply processes the 2 values passed to it with the defined function)

The formula can have any level of complexity and the key to structuring the array is with position of the brackets (items in brackets are contained in calc)

e.g

100 *((1 + 21) * ((2 * 10) + 90))

would become;

- array

  - val: 100
- array

  - func: *
  - calc

    - array

      - calc

        - array

          - val:1
        - array

          - func: +
          - val: 21
    - array

      - func: *
      - calc

        - array

          - calc

            - array

              - val: 2
            - array

              - func: *
              - val: 10
        - array

          - func: +
          - val: 90

The reason for this approach is it gives the script complete control over what functions can be passed, so as advanced custom functions can be used and to avoid the use of eval() which should in all fairness be spelt evil().

The issue here is also simplified slighly as in the actual application it uses field references rather than actual values.

**The issue I am having is with creating the array with the correct structure.**

How could i convert an equation such as 100 *((1 + 21) * ((2 * 10) + 90)) into a php array in the format above.

Something like (below) is the best i've come up with so far, but it won't work on more complex functions.

```
public function format($calc){

          if(strpos($calc, '(') !== false) $groups = explode('(', $calc);
          else $groups = array($calc);

          $x = 0;
          $y = 0;
          $mode = 0;
          $return = array($x=>array());
          foreach($groups as $i => $a) {

               if($a == '') continue;
               $a = trim($a);
               if(strpos($a, '(') !== false) $groups2 = explode(')', $a);
               else $groups2 = array($a);

               foreach($groups2 as $ii => $b) {
                    if($b == '') continue;
                    $b = trim($b);
                    if($x > 0 && !isset($return[$x]['func'])) {

                         if($this->isCalcfunction($b)) { $return[$x]['func'] = $val; $mode = 0; $y = 0; }
                         continue;
                    }
                    $line = array();
                    if(strpos($b, ' ') !== false) $vals = explode(' ', $b);
                    else $vals = array($b);

                    foreach($vals as $iii => $val) {
                         if($val == '') continue;
                         $val = trim($val);
                         if($mode == 1) {
                                   if($this->isCalcfunction($val)) { $line[$y]['func'] = $val; $mode = 0; }  
                         } else {
                                   if(is_numeric($val)) {  $line[$y]['val'] = $val; $mode = 1; $y++;}
                         }
                    }

                    if(!empty($line)){
                         $return[$x]['calc'] = $line;
                         $x++;
                    }
               }
          }

          return $return;

     }
```

I'm sure that my current approach is wrong.... the answer is likely with looping through the string and using preg_split to split on each bracket or potentially using a regex... but so far i've just been hitting brick walls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: to be honest, I didn't walk through all of that, just the final code. But wouldn't it be better to have a recursive function? (talking about `public funtionc format()`)

Comment: and I would then `preg_split` by any calc-operator, not explode by `(`

Comment: For such things, I'd use a parser https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm  or http://www.nerdparadise.com/programming/parsemathexpr  There're many, just google : "parse mathematical expression"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Yes i think looping and using preg_split is likely the best approach but i just can't get this one figured out. The processor is fine and actually really easy, id prefer to use my own processor as then it gives us complete control over the functions used. What i have put here is a lot more simplified than the actual script which involves table lookups etc. The format function i referenced is certainly the wrong approach but it does work with less complicated formulas so though it should be left for reference,

Comment: Being honest, i figured it wouldn't be hard to get a string into the correct array format, i thought the hardest part would be the processor. I'm also sure i'm suffering from coders block here more than anything else as the solution should be "relatively" simple...